# Передача Modbus RTU в android при помощи Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, микросервисы, modbus, libmodbus

подскажите, возможно ли, и как осуществить передачу данных по протоколу Modbus RTU (по проводу) в Android смартфон с последующем выводом информации на экран при помощи языка Kotlin?

Comment: Возможно, есть множество решений, если у тебя есть компорт на твоем андроиде, или конвертор интерфейса, только модбас подразумевает, что мастером будет телефон, или ты хочешь запустить Modbus-слейва на андроиде?

Comment: Yakov, Да, мастером будет мой телефон, какие мои дальнейшие действия?

Comment: идешь в гугл ищешь библиотеку которая тебе по душе http://www.biemmeitalia.net/libraries/index.html и не слишком старая, добавляешь в проект и пишешь код? как-то так?